# How do I get the current/previous view name in Ember

Tags: ember.js, viewmodel, traversal, browser-history

I am right a project and I need to be able to access the name of the previous view.

So, for instance, if I'm on page 1 and I navigate to page 2, I want to know that I came from page 1.

Basically I have a view that can be accessed from a number of screens and the content of that view will depend on the screen that if came from.

I know I can do this by passing the name across in a function, but I am wondering if there is a nicer way of doing this.

I tried some implementations with the historylocation class but I could get it working. The url kept being sent back to the base url every time I created an instance of the historylocation, which was weird.

I also see that there might be a way to do this in the router by adding

```
location: 'history'
```

but I don't know how to get this to start working afterwards then, to access the correct view name i.e. current/previous

There a way of getting this through the browser history too I guess but I was hoping to do it with Ember.
Any one have any ideas how to get these to work or better ways to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access browsing history in ember](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142654/access-browsing-history-in-ember)