# Access browsing history in ember

Tags: testing, ember.js, url-routing, html5-history

I have the following two paths to edit an object (*node*) in my application:

1. List nodes -> click edit icon
2. List nodes -> select node -> click edit button

I have the option to cancel the editing. When I cancel, I want the router (controller?) to go back to the right place. That is, if I came from the list of nodes, I want cancel to go back to "list of nodes" (`#nodes`). If I came from the node view, I want cancel to go back to the node view (`#nodes/show/node-id`). Currently this is the implementation in my `NodesEditController`:

```
SettingsApp.NodesEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['nodesIndex'],
    selectedNode: null,
    selectedNodeType: null,
    nodes: [],
    ...
    cancel: function () {
        this.stopEditing();
        this.transitionToRoute('nodes.show', this.get('content'));
    },

    ...
});
```

As you can see, the route for the `cancel` action is fixed (`nodes.show`). But in the first case, I would like to do `this.transitionToRoute('nodes.index');`. So my `cancel` method must be something like this:

```
 cancel: function () {
    this.stopEditing();
    if (some_test) { this.transitionToRoute('nodes.show', this.get('content'));
    } else { this.transitionToRoute('nodes.index'); }
 }
```

How to implement `some_test`? What can I test to know how did I get to the current route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reopen `Ember.Route` to store the `currentPath` when a route is exited:

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
  deactivate: function() {
    var applicationController = this.controllerFor('application');
    App.previousPath = applicationController.get('currentPath');
  }
});
```

Then in your cancel method:

```
goBack: function () {
    if (SettingsApp.previousPath == 'nodes.show') {
        this.transitionToRoute(SettingsApp.previousPath, this.get('content'));
    } else {
        this.transitionToRoute(SettingsApp.previousPath);
    }
},

cancel: function () {
    this.stopEditing();
    this.goBack();
},
```

Note: you might want to provide some fallback in case the app is loaded in the `nodes.edit` route.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Ember.Route.reopen`? Can I do that anywhere in my app? Sorry, complete newbie here.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. It was indeed `Ember.Route.reopen`. I have modified slightly your reply to make it more complete.